# Issues with running pytesseract in script

Tags: python, tesseract, valueerror, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract in my python script to read out a string of text in an image, but I keep getting errors. I'm now trying this code:

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files 
(x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'
# Include the above line, if you don't have tesseract executable in 
#your PATH
# Example tesseract_cmd: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-
#OCR\\tesseract'

# Simple image to string
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('IMG_9296.jpg')))
```

The IMG_9296.jpg file is located on my desktop: `~/Desktop`. I already have tesseract and pytesseract installed, as typing `tesseract` into my command line comes back with information about it.
When I type `pip install pytesseract` into my command line, I get back:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pytesseract in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pytesseract)
```

So I'm guessing that `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` is my path to pytesseract, so I tried putting that in for `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd`, but that didn't work. Either way I'm getting this error (I think from the `import pytesseract` line):

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Do I need to be entering in a different path, or move/copy pytesseract somewhere? I'm not really sure what's going on.

Comment: PIL and pillow are different - perhaps your import error is on PIL?

Answer (score 0):

First check in your command prompt by entering Code

```
!pip view pytesseract
```

If it return some info that means you have it in your system , you also need to see the PIL module also.

Now Coming on to your **main Question**:

In order to pytesseact you need to be on  **pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd** path:- 
 And more over you need to be on the path as well where the image is located.
 So what possibly you can do  is as below

**import pytesseract

import cv2



import os
os.chdir(FullPath_where_your_"tesseract.exe" is located) 



image = cv2.imread('full_path_of_your_image')

pytext = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)

print(pytext)**

Do let me know in case its not working 

*Happy learning !!*